# Generating Random Variable from Binomial Distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution

I am using r for generating  random numbers from Binomial distribution using the following code:

```
n=5
p=.7
x <-0 
for(i in 1:n) { 
  U=runif(1) 
  show (U)
  if (U < p) {
    x[i] <-x+ 1
  } 
  else {
    x[i] <- 0
  }
} 
show (x)
```

But not getting correct results.Please help me in getting correct results

Comment: just use `rbinom`

Comment: The R code is full of mistakes: e.g., the `else x[i]=0` is wrong and the `x[i] <-x+1` is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Christoph Hanck, rbinom is an easy way to generate random binomial variables:

```
n <- 5
p <- 0.7
rbinom(1, n, p)
```

I'm going to assume you'd prefer to do it in a similar fashion to the code you've provided, and make a couple of suggestions. The problem in your code is that you've set x to a number, 0, and then are referring to the ith component of x as though it were a vector; it's unclear which you want. In the following code I'll assume you've already set values for n and p:

If you want x to be binomially distributed, you could do:

```
x <-0 
for(i in 1:n) { 
  U=runif(1) 
  show (U)
  if (U < p) {
    x <- x + 1
  } 
} 
show (x)
```

or, similarly:

```
x <- 0
for(i in 1:n) x <- x + as.numeric(runif(1) < p)
```

even:

```
x <- sum(as.numeric(runif(n) < p))
```

If you want x to be a vector, each component being a bernoulli random variable (so the sum of x is binomially distributed), you could do:

```
x <- rep(NA, n)
for(i in 1:n) { 
  U=runif(1) 
  show (U)
  if (U < p) {
    x[i] <- 1
  } 
  else {
    x[i] <- 0
  }
} 
show (x)
```

Or, similarly:

```
x <- as.numeric(runif(n) < p)
```